# IIS Rewrite Content-Disposition attachment filename

Tags: iis, download, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, content-disposition

I'm not the greatest with rewrite rules but I'm trying to rename a file a download based on a querystring e.g. something like this https://example.com/images/02ec1c94de50.jpg?download=1&filename=renamethefiletothis.jpg

this is the rule I have, currently hardcoding the file to be named thisfile.jpg i want to take the URL parameter filename and replace thisfile.jpg

```
<rule name="Downloadthefile">
    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Disposition" pattern=".*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="attachment;filename=thisfile.jpg" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(^|&amp;)download=1(&amp;|$)"/>
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. What is your target URL? What do you want to rewrite this URL into?

Comment: it's to rename the file at download so when someone clicks on a link the file will download with a specific name

i've got it mostly working with the current rule
<rewrite>
           <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Downloadthefile">
     <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Disposition" pattern=".*" />
     <action type="Rewrite" value="attachment;{C:0}" />
     <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(^|&amp;)filename=(.*)$" />
     </conditions>
    </rule>
   </outboundRules></rewrite>

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get something working this isn't perfect but works.

so this url the file stored on the server is called 02ec1c94de50.jpg but when the user clicks on the link it downloads as myrenamed.jpg

https://example.com/02ec1c94de50.jpg?&filename=myrenamed.jpg

the download attribute e.g. download="myrenamed" doesn't work crossdomain so have to use the content-disposition header to rename dynamically.

```html
<rule name="Downloadthefile">
    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Disposition" pattern=".*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="attachment;{C:0}" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(^|&amp;)filename=(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```